# Is the following inequality always true?

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to prove that a certain inequality is always true but I have not been able to come up with any mathematical proof for it.
The question is this.

ab<cd 
where $a\neq b\neq c\neq d$. Where a,b,c and d are positive integers greater than 0. Where a>c and d>b. Is it always true that $d-b\geq a-c$?

Please note that I have tried several examples and this seems to always hold. I will give two examples.

Example 1. Let a=4, b=1, c=2, d=3.
Then ab<cd becomes $4\times 1<2\times 3$ and $d-b\geq a-c$? becomes $3-1\geq4-2$, which is true.

Example 2. Let a=101, b=75, c=73, d=103.
Then ab<cd becomes $101\times 75<73\times 103$ and $d-b\geq a-c$? becomes $103-75\geq101-73$, which is true.

What is the proof that this always hold?

Comment: Take $(a,b,c,d)=(5,1,3,2)$.  Then $ab<cd$ since $5<6$.  And we have $a>c$ and $d>b$. But $d-b<a-c$.

Comment: @lulu please write your counter example as a reply. I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a simple class of counterexamples, start with $$c=a-2\quad \&\quad d=b+1$$

That guarantees $a>c$ , $d>b$, and $d-b<a-c$.  We need to ensure that $ab<cd$ however.

To do that, write it out:

$$cd=(a-2)(b+1)=ab-2b+a-2>ab\iff a-2>2b$$

So, with $c,d$ defined as above, we just need to add $a-2>2b$.

One explicit example along these lines is: $$\boxed {(a,b,c,d)=(5,1,3,2)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @lulu